# How do I loop using multiple conditions for a submit button?

Tags: sql, ms-access, dao

I am writing a function that checks if the amount paid is equal or more to a number of items selected if they are checked. For this example there are 10 items with 10 check boxes. I could check one or more boxes in any order.If an item or more meets the condition it is cleared otherwise it remains.

```vb
Public Sub processItem1()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim pr As DAO.Recordset, so As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim strSQL2 As String

Set db = CurrentDb

    strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM PharmSales WHERE PharmSalesID= (SELECT MAX(PharmSalesID) FROM PharmSales WHERE HospitalNo='" & Me.txtRegNo & "' And TDate = #" &    Format(Me.txtTDate, "M\/dd\/yyyy") & "# AND SalesItem1 = '" & Me.txtSalesItem1 & "')"
    strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM tblItem WHERE ItemName = '" & Me.txtSalesItem1 & "'"
Set pr = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL1)
Set so = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL2)

With pr
If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then  'Ensure that the recordset contains records
.MoveLast
.MoveFirst
 If .Updatable Then  'To ensure record is not locked by another user
 .Edit  'Must start an update with the edit statement
 ![DispQty1] = Nz(![DispQty1] + Me.txtSalesQty1.Value, 0)
  .Update
End If
End If

 pr.Close  'Make sure you close the recordset..
 Set pr = Nothing  '...and set it to nothing
Set db = Nothing
End With

With so
If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then  'Ensure that the recordset contains records
.MoveLast
.MoveFirst
 If .Updatable Then  'To ensure record is not locked by another user
 .Edit  'Must start an update with the edit statement
![Stock_Out] = Nz(![Stock_Out] + Me.txtSalesQty1.Value, Me.txtSalesQty1.Value)
 ![SO_Date] = Me.txtTDate
  ![Stock_In] = Nz(![Stock_In] + 0, 0)
  .Update  'And finally we will need to confirm the update

End If
End If
 so.Close  'Make sure you close the recordset..
 ExitSub:
 Set so = Nothing  '...and set it to nothing
Set db = Nothing

   End With
    End Sub
```

For processItem2:

```vb
Public Sub processItem2()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim pr As DAO.Recordset, so As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim strSQL2 As String

Set db = CurrentDb

    strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM PharmSales WHERE PharmSalesID= (SELECT MAX(PharmSalesID) FROM PharmSales WHERE HospitalNo='" & Me.txtRegNo & "' And TDate = #" & Format(Me.txtTDate, "M\/dd\/yyyy") & "# AND SalesItem2 = '" & Me.txtSalesItem2 & "')"
    strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM tblItem WHERE ItemName = '" & Me.txtSalesItem2 & "'"
Set pr = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL1)
Set so = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL2)

With pr
If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then  'Ensure that the recordset contains records
.MoveLast
.MoveFirst
 If .Updatable Then  'To ensure record is not locked by another user
 .Edit  'Must start an update with the edit statement
 ![DispQty2] = Nz(![DispQty2] + Me.txtSalesQty2.Value, 0)
  .Update
End If
End If

 pr.Close  'Make sure you close the recordset..
 Set pr = Nothing  '...and set it to nothing
Set db = Nothing
End With

With so
If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then  'Ensure that the recordset contains records
.MoveLast
.MoveFirst
 If .Updatable Then  'To ensure record is not locked by another user
 .Edit  'Must start an update with the edit statement
 ![Stock_Out] = Nz(![Stock_Out] + Me.txtSalesQty2.Value, Me.txtSalesQty2.Value)
 ![SO_Date] = Me.txtTDate
  ![Stock_In] = Nz(![Stock_In] + 0, 0)
  .Update  'And finally we will need to confirm the update
End If
End If
 so.Close  'Make sure you close the recordset..
 ExitSub:
 Set so = Nothing  '...and set it to nothing
Set db = Nothing

End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever copy&paste code like this. It is a maintenance nightmare.

You can loop over objects by concatenating their name at runtime:

```vb
Me("txtSalesItem" & i)      ' form control
pr("DispQty" & i).Value     ' recordset field
```

etc.

Side note:

```
With recordset
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst
```

These MoveLast/MoveFirst commands are unnecessary. You only need them if you want to get the correct `.RecordCount` of a recordset.

Comment: Also, `Updatable` to my knowledge refers to the _Recordset_, not the actual record.

Comment: Thank you Andre for those observations. I will like you to be more explicit on where and how to insert the ("txtSalesItem" & i) based on the example provided

Comment: @LibertyCrownInfotech: Please try yourself. Wherever you have a numbered field/control name like `txtSalesItem1` or `DispQty1`, you do this. Another note: the whole thing would become much simpler by converting the numbered fields into a separate table "Today_Sales", and change it into a subform. Then you could simply loop its records without any dynamic name constructing.

Comment: @Andre. The Today_Sales is actually a set of controls that display the result from another table dynamically.